# select a single value from table into a field from while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a select option to get data from a table by using while loop

```
$select_material_code = "SELECT material FROM tbl_material";
$get_material_code = mysqli_query ($con, $select_material_code);
$options_material_Code = "--Select material Code--";
while ($result_material_code = mysqli_fetch_array($get_material_code))
{
    $options_material_Code = $options_material_Code."<option>$result_material_code[0]</option>";    
}
```

All data is coming into the list as expected, so, i want to continue selection data from selection option and fetch a value into next textbox, but i cannot get it.
please help....

Comment: Do you mean, you want to get data from option value that you click? I suggest you to use JQuery AJAX @Ratana

Comment: I mean, if i select value from drop down list which already fetch data from a table then textbox value will get data from database at the same time. Note: Table has material & name. Drop down list is material, but i need its name into textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select_material_code = "SELECT material FROM tbl_material";
$get_material_code = mysqli_query ($con, $select_material_code);
$options_material_Code = "--Select material Code--";
while ($result_material_code = mysqli_fetch_array($get_material_code))
  {
     $options_material_Code =
      $result_material_Code."<option>$result_material_code[0]</option>";    
  }
```

Comment: code is working well. what i want is dynamic data from drop down list into textbox. Table tbl_material have 'material' column which show up in drop down list, next step is when i select any value from list then i get value into textbox from column 'name'